# Bulma Select form element - how to detect "select" or change event when an option is selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bulma

I'm trying to use the [Select](https://bulma.io/documentation/form/select/) form element from Bulma and can't figure out the most basic of questions... how to detect when an option is selected by the user?  I want to call a function to change the website's language when a language select option is selected but can't figure out how to register a "select" event.

[image]

The element works just fine and toggles between two languages however what do I need to do to detect when one of the options is actually selected?

```
<div className="navbar-item">
  <div className="select">
    <select>
      <option>English</option>
      <option>Chinese</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using `onChange` and `onClick` events but neither of them work, for example:

```
<div className="navbar-item">
  <div className="select">
    <select>
      <option onChange={() => changeLanguage('en')}>English</option>
      <option onChange={() => changeLanguage('cn')}>Chinese</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do I need to create separate React state vars for this and manage the selection myself?

---

**ANSWER**

Was able to piece together bits from the various answers get this working, I tried updating the answer so it's correct but also posting here for the benefit of the community.

Here's the JSX with Select options:

```
    <div className="navbar-item">
      <div className="select">
        <select onChange={(e) => changeLanguage(e)}>
          <option value="en" id="en">English</option>
          <option value="cn" id="cn">中文</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the corresponding change language function:

```
    const changeLanguage = event => {
        i18n.changeLanguage(event.target.value);
      };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `onChange` handler on `select` element instead of `option`, here's react code to handle option change and alter your state

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    lang: "eng" // set english by default
  };

  onSelect = ev => {
    this.setState({ lang: ev.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navbar-item">
        <div className="select">
          <select onChange={this.onSelect}>
            <option value="eng">English</option>
            <option value="ch">Chinese</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to put the onChange on the select instead of the option.

So:

```
  <div className="select" onChange={(e) => changeLanguage(e)}>
    <select>
      <option value="en">English</option>
      <option value="cn">Chinese</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

From there you can use react reference to get the value of the select. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Get the value of the select field and write a function called changeLanguage that has some ternary operation to detect what langauge is currently select and the logic to trigger on language changes. I.E.

```
if(selectId.val === 'en') //do some code
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right in that hoisting the onChange() function to the select makes it so it gets called now... however re: getting the value unfortunately I cannot use React refs in this case since this is for a React Functional Component :(. Per the React documentation `You may not use the ref attribute on function components because they don’t have instances.`

Comment: Ok you're solution was close except it was missing the event params and also the `value` key which Natnael's answer helped identify.. you had `() => changeLanguage()` after changing to `(e) => changeLanguage(e)` and also adding the `value=x` property to each option it now works.  I've gone ahead and updated your answer and accepted it, thanks.